# Additional question to "Intended random rotation of figures "

Tags: floats, geometry

Several days ago I asked a question about random rotation of figures and the user "Skillmon" provided an excellent answer: [Intended random rotation of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696930/intended-random-rotation-of-figures)
Now I would like to go one step further: I would like to create a picture gallery in such a way that I get 3 columns and I would like the images to be rotated randomly. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx, multirow}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,graphicx,array}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696930/intended-random-rotation-of-figures
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \random { \int_rand:nn {-10} {10} }
\cs_new:Npn \randomsize { \int_rand:nn {3} {6} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \foreach \s in {1,...,200}{%
       %\IfFileExists{DATEINAME}{DANN-TEIL}{SONST-TEIL}
        \IfFileExists{D:/folder1/folder2/pictures\s.jpg}%
 {\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \def\ig{%
   \includegraphics[width=.245\textwidth,keepaspectratio,angle=\random]{D:/folder1/folder2/pictures\s.jpg}
   }%
 \node [inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\phantom{\ig}};%
 \clip[rounded corners=0mm] ($(mypicture.south west)+(1mm,1mm)$) rectangle ($(mypicture.north east)-(1mm,1mm)$);%
 \node[inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\ig};%
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Everything works very nice except that the corners of the pictures are cut off which I don´t wont. Can anyone explain how to solve this problem, please? Thanks in advance!