# How to avoid cut corners of pictures in a collage?

Tags: floats, geometry

I am working on a picture gallery of three colums and randomly rotated pictures:

```
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx, multirow}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,graphicx,array}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696930/intended-random-rotation-of-figures
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \random { \int_rand:nn {-10} {10} }
\cs_new:Npn \randomsize { \int_rand:nn {3} {6} }
\ExplSyntaxOff


    \begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \foreach \s in {1,...,200}{%
        \IfFileExists{D:/folder 1/folder 2\s.jpg}%
 {\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \def\ig{%
   \includegraphics[width=.245\textwidth,keepaspectratio,angle=\random]{example-image-duck}
   }%
 \node [inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\phantom{\ig}};%
 \clip[rounded corners=0mm] ($(mypicture.south west)+(1mm,1mm)$) rectangle ($(mypicture.north east)-(1mm,1mm)$);%
 \node[inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\ig};%
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{center}
```

Everything works very nice expect that some corners of the pictures are cut off but instead of this I like to have overlappings. Is there a possibility of avoid the "cutted" corners of each picture? Can anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're evaluating `\random` twice per picture, so your `\clip` has a different `\random` than your actual picture.

Comment: Also, what is your `\clip` supposed to do? And why are you drawing your pictures twice (once as `\phantom` once normally)?

Comment: @Skillmon: Ok, I must confess that I am not as skilled as you and other developers and/or users. I adopted the code from somewhere else (can´t remember the source). Until this "idea" which is described above I was quite satisfied with the results. I removed the \phantom and the result is looking much better! Once again thank you for looking at my problem.